# Return value from c++ function via out-argument

Tags: c++, scope, reference, arguments, move

I want to return non-primitive type (e.g. std::vector) via out-argument by reference.

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& out_vec)
{
    out_vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    foo(v);

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and prints "1 2 3" as expected, but I worry about lifetime of object std::vector{1, 2, 3} from foo().

Maybe this would be correct?

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& out_vec)
{
    out_vec = std::move(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3});
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    foo(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need to explicitly use `move` here as `std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}` is already an rvalue so the **move assignment `operator=` can be used here.**

Comment: why do you worry about the lifetime? `std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};` is a temporary. Its lifetime ends at the end of the expression, and thats ok, because you make a copy of it

Comment: in case thats why you worry: `out_vec` is not a reference to that temporary, its a reference to `v` in `main`.

Comment: You cannot reassign a reference to point somewhere else. This is still pointing to the caller-supplied object and rewriting its contents. No lifetime issues to be expected.

Comment: btw if this wouldnt work as expected, you'd have the same issue when `foo` would return by value rather than out-reference: `v = foo();` this is more or less exactly same situation as you have now inside `foo`

Comment: C++ is not Java or python.  When you did this: `out_vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};` -- you are creating a full *copy* of the vector, not assigning a reference or similar to `out_vec`.  Thus it doesn't matter what eventually happens to the value on the right side of the `=` sign.

Comment: If a purpose of a function is to produce a new value, then it is generally better to return it by value, not through a reference parameter. Is there a good reason not to do it in your case?

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector{1, 2, 3}` is a temporary object. Its lifetime will certainly end when `foo()` returns (even before that, technically).

Nobody cares.

Before its lifetime comes to a quick finish it will be assigned to `out_vec`, which is perfectly healthy, and its life continues. The temporary object will be a distant memory, but `out_vec` will continue to thrive, in good health, and with a bright future ahead of it.

Throwing `std::move` into the mix does not accomplish anything useful, and makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

> but I worry about lifetime of object std::vector{1, 2, 3} from foo().

`out_vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};` is [move assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment) since `std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}` is an *rvalue expression* which means the [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) `vector& operator=( vector&& other );` defined by `std::vector` is **viable** and will be used automatically i.e., you don't explicitly need to explicitly write `std::move` in your example.

In other words, the two snippets are *equivalent*.

Comment: its not necessary to move from `std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};` to avoid any lifetime issues.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes but i didn't say that it is necessary anywhere. Did my answer implied this? Also the answer is specific to modern C++(from C++11) and in modern c++ `out_vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};` is "move" assignment.

Comment: question asks if the code is ok or if they need to add `std::move`, you say its ok because it is already moved. I just say that it would be ok also without move semantics.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I do not mean to say that it wouldn't be ok without move semantics. I am(the answer) saying that the two code snippets are equivalent. Also adding explanation for whether or not it will be ok without move semantics in the answer is optional as OP specifically asks about the given code snippets.